# Zip Archive Library decompression with AES-256

Tags: c++, aes, php-ziparchive, winzip

I am using Zip Archive library for compressing and decompressing files, i needed to enable AES encryption so by Uncommenting

```
#def ZIP_AES
```

in the _features.h file included with the library and recompiling I got CZipException for decompression

#### "WinZip AES encryption has not been enabled for the library, but is required to decompress the archive."

Am i missing something? please any guide would so much appreciated.

Comment: Did you rebuild the library?  Did you also notice that AES isn't available in the free version?

Comment: thanks for the response i have the full version and Yes i have rebuilt the whole library again.

Comment: Thanks Again Oil you've guided me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Oli Charlesworth; there was a conflict between the lib file produced from the free library and the one i bought thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I strangely got this error when the program in question needed Pkzip encryption, not AES encryption as the message suggested.
(While this isn't OP's problem, I'm mentioning it for future readers)